# Tomcat Struts 2 Ubuntu server very slow after action class

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, struts2

I have a webapp. It runs very well in all the environs I have tested so far. That is except for the Production environ in the Rackspace cloud.

I am using `Tomcat 6` with `struts 2.1.8` and `mysql` as the database On a `Ubuntu 11.10 server`. Normally a request might take 1 second to complete in a healthy environ. From my logs I have determined that the Action is taking 1 second to complete. I am testing this with an Action Timer interceptor. After the action method executes it takes about 15 seconds for the page to display. So I don't think the problem is DB related or Action class related.

What could be causing this delay ?

```
java -version :

java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I put a test.jsp in the app root and hitting that directly in the browser is fast response.

Comment: Is your test/QA environment also in the same Rackspace cloud?

Comment: No but I am running it in many different places and its fine.

Comment: Could it be the Open JDK JRE ?

Comment: It could be, but it doesn't seem likely. You're probably not going to get the answer on here -- there are just too many variables and not enough details. You are in the best position to figure this out, dive in and troubleshoot. A PreResultListener might help you time how long it takes from when the action finishes processing until the browser receives the response. You might also look at PageSpeed to see if there are problems with the client-side rendering speed.

Comment: I had this line in my sitemesh layout page <sx:head cache="false"/>. Changibng that to true reduces the delay considerably. However it is still about 5 seconds to load each page now. I will use the Pagespeed profiler from google to see if I can improve that. I dont understand why this delay didnt appear in the other environments though.

Comment: I used the PageSpeed tool and YSlow and now I have good cruising speed for my site. Thanks for your advice it was very useful. Applied Compression gzip to tomcat... very useful stuff.

Comment: Glad to hear that the speed issues are improving. PageSpeed is a great resource for optimizing the rendering times. I moved my comment to an answer, since it wound up being useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem likely that its related to the OpenJDK JVM.

A [PreResultListener](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/PreResultListener.html) might help you time how long it takes from when the action finishes processing until the browser receives the response.

You might also look at [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to see if there are problems with the client-side rendering speed.